# Java Elasticsearch client: throws ConnectException when connecting from local to ES in Google Cloud VM

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an elasticsearch cluster running in google-compute-engine(VMs), and I am trying to connect from my Java program.

ES instante in the google-cloud has an external-ip & internal-ip.
I have configured the external-ip for connecting, and all the firewall settings are enabled to connect.

Still it seems like, the internal-ip is using somewhere by the client while writing myd data to ES.

**10.240.0.237**  is the internal-ip

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /10.240.0.237:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
```

Code

```
public class ESClient {
        final static Node[] esNodes = new Node[1];
        static String indexName = "sa-sonarshock-log";
        public static Client getClient(){
            if(esNodes[0] == null){
                esNodes[0] = _setupNode();
            }
            return esNodes[0].client();
        }
        public static Node _setupNode(){
            Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("cluster.name", "es-tifc-retro-testing")
                    .put("http.enabled", false)
                    .put("transport.tcp.port", "9300-9400")
                    .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
                    .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "estifcretrotest-es-tifc-retro-testing-1-vm")
                    .build();    

            return nodeBuilder().settings(settings).client(true).node();
        }   
        public static Map<String, Object> putJsonDocument(String title, String content, Date postDate, 
                String[] tags, String author){
            Map<String, Object> jsonDocument = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            jsonDocument.put("title", title);
            jsonDocument.put("conten", content);
            jsonDocument.put("postDate", postDate);
            jsonDocument.put("tags", tags);
            jsonDocument.put("author", author);
            return jsonDocument;
        }   
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Client esClient = getClient();
            CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = esClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexName);
            createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
            esClient.prepareIndex(indexName, "default", "1")
            .setSource(putJsonDocument("ElasticSearch: Java API",
                                       "ElasticSearch provides the Java API, all operations "
                                       + "can be executed asynchronously using a client object.",
                                       new Date(),
                                       new String[]{"elasticsearch"},
                                       "Remis Haroon")).execute().actionGet();
            esNodes[0].close();
        }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with elasticsearch, looks like a network error. Have you tried a ssh, telnet or nc on this particular host:port ? For instance nc 10.240.0.237 9300 -v   will tell you if the host can be reached on this port.

Comment: @devlearn , this not network issue (for sure), since , i didn't know the internal-ip of ES-server [which is 10.240.0.237].is showing in the error log

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the given host and port by some other ways then elastic search ?

Comment: @devlearn, yes I am able to connect through browser

Comment: You mean you hit port 9300 via http using a browser ? And it displays "This is not a HTTP port" ? If so I'd suggest you check if your browser has any proxy settings and if this is not the case , and port 9300 responds, try to use this particular port in the node builder instead of the range.

Comment: @devlearn, No, i tried port 9200, and it worked, that proves theres no n/w access issue

Comment: Your code explicitly requires a connection to range 9300-9400  so using the browser on port 9200 does not prove anything at all on the network side. Point your browser to the exact port ( try 9300 for instance ) and try it out. A connection timeout usually happens when the socket cannot be opened on the remote side. So chances are that you have a firewall somewhere in between the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting on port 9300, but I think you want port 9200.